# Validation rules in Laravel for joining two columns

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-4

Is there a way to build a validation in Laravel which checks if two columns together are unique in a table?

So for example if there is [(A, B)] in my table, then the input (A, A) or (B, B) should pass the validation but (A, B) again have to fail.

For example like this:

```
DB::table('mytable')
            ->where([
                ['col1', $item->col1],
                ['col2', $item->col2]
            ])
            ->exists();
```

But I want to do it within a validation, so something simular to this:

```
public function validate() {
        return Validator::make($this->attributes, [
            'col1|col2' => 'unique:mytable',
            //....
        ])->errors();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for validation of uniqueness of composite indexes (multiple columns), this is not possible unless you create a custom validation rule.

You can create a custom validation rule, see https://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

```
// Example:
// 'col1' => 'unique_with:table,col2,col3,col4,etc'
// 'col2' => doesn't need to check uniqueness again, because we did it for col1

Validator::extend('unique_with', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $request = request()->all();

  // $table is always the first parameter
  // You can extend it to use dots in order to specify: connection.database.table
  $table = array_shift($parameters);

  // Add current column to the $clauses array
  $clauses = [
    $attribute => $value,
  ];

  // Add the rest  
  foreach ($parameters as $column) {
    if (isset($request[$column])) {
        $clauses[$column] = $request[$column];
    }
  }

  // Query for existence.
  return ! DB::table($table)
            ->where($clauses)
            ->exists();
});
```

place that code in the `boot()` method of a service provider, you can use `App\Http\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`
I didn't test it, but it should help you to go forward and make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: what we can do if we have uniqueness of composite indexes with multiple table joins (with Relations).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to require them if either exists, but make sure both are unique. This should work for you:

```
'col1' => 'unique:mytable|required_with:col2',
'col2' => 'unique:mytable|required_with:col1'
```

Comment: That's not what OP is asking. The question states explicitly "_Is there a way to build a validation in Laravel which checks if two columns together are unique in a table?_" . He's talking about compound indexes. Which is not possible at the moment, only with a custom validation rule.

Comment: @Frondor Sometimes it's difficult to discern directly what someone is asking. This particular answer seems to best fit the example provided by OP. If this is not what OP wants, they're free to downvote me into oblivion.